# How does Magento MVC differ from classical MVC / Zend Framework MVC?

Tags: magento-1.7, mvc

How does Magento MVC differ from classical MVC or Zend Framework MVC? Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: You're asking a pretty big question. Can you narrow it down?

Comment: I don't think there is any implemented "classical MVC" :) Every implementation has decisions and therefore you can't compare it in detail. This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764049/how-mvc-works-in-magento

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While Magento's MVC uses the same base controller classes, almost everything else is custom. Off the top of my head.

1. Module frontnames are defined in Magento's `config.xml`
2. Since Magento has its own module structure, parsing the configuration to match a module front name with a module is completely custom, and is achieved in a match method in a series of custom router object
3. The above mentioned routers have custom code for automatically requiring (vs. `__autoload` the base controller files.
4. There's a configuration based and database based rewrite system for changing MVC routing logic
5. Magento's event/observer system lets you inject your own router object which may change routing logic, or bypass it entirely
6. The handoff from controller action to view is completly different — Magento has a view system/layout-object distinct from Zend Frameworks view system

Comment: So basically Magento has configuration based MVC right?

Comment: @Su123 In over simplified terms, yes — although an argument could be made that Magento's is a hybrid approach.

Comment: :Exactly, due to `observers/events` Magento achieves the dynamic behavior and at the same time other MVC related stuff achieves  `continuous` behavior. So in that case we can define Magento is a hybrid approach. Thanks a lot for the expalation. +1

Comment: Great analysis, thanks Alan!  I know I often read similar oversimplifications regarding it being a Zend Framework, which is apparently "sort of" accurate...this helped me understand why :)